# Excel VBA Dominoes team selection randomly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new on this and need help with a macro I need to create.  The goal is to randomly select partners for dominoes matches from a list of names.

**Details:**
I will have a list of players in column "B", every day could be a different amount of players and different names. In column "A" those players will have a unique number. The macro should combine those players in pairs and those partners will go against another pair both pairs randomly selected.  I will specify on a cell how many times each player will play on that day.  The constraints are that:

1. No two players should play together on a team for the second time until all combinations have been used, and so on.
2. No two same teams should play against each other for the second time until all combinations have been used.

What I need back from the macro is in …

- Column D: Team 1, (Player 1 number).
- Column E: Team 1, (Player 2 number).
- Column F: Team 2, (Player 1 number).
- Column G: Team 2, (Player 2 number).

I only need the number since my plan is to get the name from the master list with a `vlookup`.  Each row will be a different match.  If for example, I have 8 players and each will play 5 times, at the end, I should have 10 rows with the matches:

```
8 players x 5 games per player = 40 / 4 players each match = 10
```

Please let me know if you have any questions,
Thanks.

**This is the code i have so far:**

```
Sub SelectRandomPlayers()

    Dim players() As String, selectedPlayers(3) As String
    Dim playerRange As Range
    Dim i As Long, c As Long, writeRow As Long, ub As Long, selectedIndex As Long, j As Long, ub2 As Long

    writeRow = 2

    Set playerRange = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    c = playerRange.count
    ub = c - 1
    ReDim players(ub)

    For i = 0 To ub
        players(i) = playerRange.Cells(i + 1).Value2
    Next i

    Do
        For i = 0 To 3
            ub2 = UBound(players)
            selectedIndex = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, ub2)
            selectedPlayers(i) = players(selectedIndex)

            For j = selectedIndex To ub2
                If j < ub2 Then players(j) = players(j + 1)
            Next j

            If ub2 > 0 Then ReDim Preserve players(ub2 - 1)
        Next i

        Range("D" & writeRow).Value2 = selectedPlayers(0)
        Range("E" & writeRow).Value2 = selectedPlayers(1)
        Range("F" & writeRow).Value2 = selectedPlayers(2)
        Range("G" & writeRow).Value2 = selectedPlayers(3)
        writeRow = writeRow + 1
    Loop While UBound(players) > 0
End Sub
```

**I still can't figure how to change it so I can have more than one match per player and comply with the constraints.**

Comment: Which bit of writing the macro are you having trouble with?

Comment: The whole thing. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid the question is "too broad" to be useful as a SO question.

Comment: How can i add the code i have so far?

Comment: Click the "edit" link at the bottom left of the question, and then just paste in the code you have (and then highlight it and press the "{}" button - but someone else can do that for you if you don't get that bit right).  And also include in the question why the code is not doing what you expect it to.

Comment: Thanks, i just did.